# Is Razor a Step Backwards?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need some convincing on the Razor View Engine.

From what I can tell, Microsoft have simply re-introduced inline code back into markup; weren't code-behind pages originally introduced to eradicate this?

I assume (and hope) that I am missing something :)

Comment: Do you have some particular resources on it or examples in mind?

Comment: For me it is simply a nicer / tidier syntax for what you would have typically done using standard <% %> blocks using the ASPX view engine in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Step back from where? WebForms allows/encourages SQL inside your mark-up. The MVC2 engine is similar to Razor but with much clumsier syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Razor is not for writing your business logic in your view.
Razor is for iterating over model and converting it to html. Your business logic is in controller besides even in WebForms view engine you did the same looping only with a more verbose syntax. Razor has cleaner syntax. It doesn't bring anything else with it.

Answer (score 2):

razor is best used with MVC. Yes it does reintroduce inline code. but it is about separation of code.

Your razor code should not have any logic in it. It really should be used to simply get your data onto a page (small amounts of logic e.g If Data= True THen Should this section, are ok tho)

but all business logic is still in your controller/codebehind

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start looking into ASP.NET MVC first. There aren't (or shouldn't be) any code-behinds.

Then compare Web Forms View Engine with Razor View Engine. That should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Razor is about making the page more readable by getting rid of bulky `<% %>` and allowing you to create your own render methods through delegates.

If anything by giving you neat shorthands for dealing with well prepared data it allows you views to *look* more like HTML, encouraging you NOT to put inline code to process data too much.

Everything that is done in a view should relate to rendering, whether its in Razor syntax or not.

As other answers point out have a look into the structure of an MVC application, all data processing should already be done by the time it comes to render a view.